# How to play a BGM and know current playback time on in cocos2d ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on a IOS game based on music, and a strict synchronize between background music and global timer is necessary, so I'm looking for some way to play music AND at the same time knowing which exact position the music is playing on at each frame update.

the `OALSimpleAudio` Doesn't have such kind of interface. Are there any better solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OALSimpleAudio Background-Music (OALAudioTrack) uses the AVAudioPlayer.

Try:

```
[[[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] backgroundTrack] player] currentTime]
```

Comment: any idea on how would u do this for cocos2dx? (since i want to make my game for android and ios)

Comment: i'm not that familiar with the x-Version of the cocos2d-Engine. But in Version 3.6 it has a function `getCurrentTime()` in the `AudioEngine`-Class. [AudioEngine.cpp](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/cocos/audio/AudioEngine.cpp#L323) Maybe this will help you or at least point you in the right direction.