# Cocos2dx 3.3 Getting background music playback time

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to get the current playback time of the background music (since i want to synchronize game events with this sound track)

Would anyone happen to know how to achieve this?

I've found that for normal cocos2d it would be something as seen on this question:

[How to play a BGM and know current playback time on in cocos2d ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653781/how-to-play-a-bgm-and-know-current-playback-time-on-in-cocos2d-ios)

And a possible solution for cocos2dx that I found:

> What I have been doing so far is saving the clock time immediately
>   after starting playing the music, and then on each update I get the
>   current clock time and compare it to the saved clock time when the
>   music was started, giving me the time since the music was started.

As seen on this post: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/audio-syncing-simpleaudioengine-buffer-position/8488

But he mentions that it eventually gets out of synch (the longer the music plays)

Thanks.